# background size changes when changing to fixed with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a couple of DIVS on with background size cover

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

But when i change content on that page from relative to fixed (using javascript) all the background sizes get messed up.
Any ideas what i should be looking for in my code?

is there a javascript jQuery way to resize backgrounds to "cover" again.
(except doing the math and cropping with a script of course)

Found pretty much the same question on here, but without any answers.

Comment: Are you sure the dimensions for the divs aren't changing when you make the switch to fixed?  There's no need to "resize" backgrounds again.  CSS is instantaneous with that kind of change.  In any case, we would need some kind of example code demonstrating the behaviour.  Think you can make a demo for us on http://jsfiddle.net or in the SO code editor?

Answer (score 0):

First thing fixed property is not relative

position : relative; and depends on the covers

when you are using position:fixed; it just uses the whole window to be position element

try with `position:relative;` in css and so the divs are dependent on other divs

Hope helps